# Error while creating projects using openshift templates

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, openshift-origin, kubernetes-pvc

I have created a template for my project on openshift, but when I pass the parameters and create the project it get a pop up like the following.

[image: This is the error I am getting]

ERROR:

`**Some resources will not be created: The following resource versions are not supported by the server: API version v1 for kind persistent volume claim**`

Seems like the PVC version is not compatible. While earlier, I used the same PVC object and it used to work fine.

This is the pvc resource I am trying to create

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "mongodb",
        "annotations":{
            "volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class":"innershift-storage"
          }
    },
    "spec": {
        "accessModes": ["ReadWriteOnce"],
        "resources": {
            "requests": {
                "storage": "1Gi"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to create the same PVC resource using REST API, and it worked. But it doesn't work when I pass parameters in the template.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: What's your Kuberenetes version?

Comment: Not sure about kubernetes, but it is openshift 3.6. The documentation has mentioned kubernetes 1.7 somewhere. Although not entirely sure.

Comment: It sounds like something like `"kind": "persistent volume claim"` might be in the template definition. Is the above `PersistentVolumeClaim` resource definition copy pasted from the problematic template?

Comment: I would isolate this `PersistentVolumeClaim` spec into `pvc.yaml`, say, and then run `oc create -f pvc.yaml` on the command line to see what happens there (in terms of detailed error messages, etc.)